# Can we use "yours" twice in succession?

Tags: commas, repetition

Can we use *yours* twice in succession? As in:

> My sign governs my style; and yours, yours.

Any other possible usage? Is my example otherwise grammatically correct?

Comment: Sure, why not? And yes it is correct.

Comment: When you say "sign" do you mean the astrological star sign?

Comment: I don't think I would include the comma. Though it is grammatically correct, and it is used, it is a structure I would tend to avoid. It can sound confusing and a bit silly when spoken. You really need to make light of it with a smile and a gesture of some sort if you do use it.

Comment: '_My_ sign governs my style – and _yours_, yours.' would appear less garden-pathy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's right

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Gardenpathy? What if I replace "and" with "as does"?

Comment: Still probably grammatical; a comma or dash after 'style' would still be helpful; “my sign governs my style, and your style governs yours” would still seem the logical way of putting this. I can't see any vast advantage in the deletions you suggest. Any improvements considered attributable to snazzier style are more than offset, in my opinion, by the difficulty encountered in analysing the deleted forms.

Comment: @WS2 The sentence was begging for a comma. What if I insert a comma before "and"? (Like an Oxford comma)

Comment: "The English test asked me to choose between _your_ and _yours_; _yours_ was the correct answer."

Comment: @gauravtechno Yes I would definitely have a comma or a dash after *style*.

Comment: ***Why do you think there is any rule in English forbidding using the same word twice in a row?***  I honestly want to know, because people keep asking this same question even though it just doesn’t make any sense phrased like **so so** I figure somebody out there has published some mythological non-rule that people are suffering because of. Just because it isn't what you think it **is is** no reason to think it's what it isn't either.

Comment: @tchrist It's just that I don't follow any 'rules' as such. I say what communicates things well and sounds right to me.

Comment: @tchrist Here in India, it is very uncommon to use the same word twice in a row. So it sounds wierd to me. I just wanted to confirm.

Comment: @gauravtechno - Things like "uncommon" and "sounds odd" are not the same as "grammatically incorrect". Put another way, just because you _can_ doesn't mean you _should._

Comment: @J.R. I like to sound like Shakespeare at times.

Comment: There's the contrastive focus reduplication usage: 'The house may be yours, but with the mortgage you've got, it's not _yours_ yours'. But this smacks of a request for a list.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, English is flexible enough to do this. Repetition is sometimes used for emphasis, and we can conjure some examples that would put the word *yours* twice in succession without breaking any grammatical rules. For example:

> All of what I have is yours – yours and yours alone.
>
> I think this should be yours, yours and not his.
>
> Everything I gave you today is yours: yours to keep, yours to cherish, yours to treasure.

Lovers sometimes write to each other using such prose. In a letter from Louise Whitfield to Andrew Carnegie:

> “I am yours, yours, all yours, for you have thrown the mantle of your great love around me, and I am no more cold and trembling, but warm and strong.”

And here's an example written by Canadian naturalist John A. Livingston:

> “Wildlife is yours; yours to manipulate in your own best interest.”

And in a work of fiction by Amanda Hemingway:

> “My world will become yours, yours mine — and all that we have achieved will not be lost.”

Comment: But your examples (except, possibly, the last) are not equivalent to the original.  In the original the first "yours" refers to "sign", while the second refers to "style".  Simply using the word twice for emphasis is an entirely different scenario.

Comment: @HotLicks - True; that's a good point. I am answering this part of the O.P.'s question: "Any other possible usage?"

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly! That's what I've been wanting to say.

Comment: @gauravtechno - If your question is specifically about that particular usage, then see my last example. Of course, one could put the conjunction _and_ in there, but it's not required.

Comment: @J.R. - nice answer. Good examples.

Answer (score 0):

It seems plausible to me that there might be a grammatical constraint preventing double "yours", since there is at least one such constraint known, the "double -ing" constraint discovered by Ross in 1972 and much discussed since (for instance [here](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/gerund-participles.pdf)).  However, I find the examples of "yours yours" I've seen so far to be acceptable.